# What's the difference or relationship between Type and TypeInfo?

Tags: .net, reflection, types

I cannot fully understand when to use one or another. They are so similar that it's confusing me every now and them. When it comes to reflection, I don't know whether to use the plain Type or TypeInfo.

.NET Framework itself adds more confusion with things like `assembly.DefinedTypes`. It retrieves an `IEnumerable<TypeInfo>` where I supposed it would be of `IEnumerable<Type>`. Also, there is a `typeInfo.AsType()` method. What's the meaning of that? are they interchangeable?

Moreover, they have methods that are really similar.

It seems that TypeInfo is like a more powerful version of the classic `Type`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A TypeInfo object represents the type definition itself, whereas a
>   Type object represents a reference to the type definition. Getting a
>   TypeInfo object forces the assembly that contains that type to load.
>   In comparison, you can manipulate Type objects without necessarily
>   requiring the runtime to load the assembly they reference.

So the `Type` provides a shallower representation of the object data, i.e, providing the name of the type as a string.

Where as `TypeInfo` provides a richer representation of the type including lists of members, implemented interfaces, and the base type.

The differences are explained in greater detail [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/evolving-the-reflection-api/).

Comment: Note that according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/ and http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2016/05/microsoft-reconsiders-reflection-serialisation-changes-for-net-core/ this was targeting the .Net core, but Microsoft has reversed it at the end.