# What's the difference between type definition and type reference?

Tags: c#, clr

I am reading the book `CLR via C#` by `Jeffrey Richter`.

In `Chapter 23(23.3.2)`, it says `"A System.Type object represents a type reference(as opposed to a type definition)."`

What do the type reference and type definition mean here?

Comment: It is language that perhaps got affected a bit too much by the CLR spec.  Metadata in an assembly distinguishes TypeDef and TypeRef.  You get a TypeDef for a type declaration, using the class, struct or delegate keywords in C#.  A TypeRef appears where ever you *use* a type declared elsewhere.  Such as you'd do with Object.GetType() or the typeof keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is contrasting `System.Type` with `System.TypeInfo`.  From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A TypeInfo object represents ***the type definition itself***, whereas a Type object represents a ***reference to the type definition***.

The `System.TypeInfo` for a class can only be instantiated if the assembly that implements the class (the type definition) is loaded or loadable.  To instantiate a `System.Type`, the only requirement is that the current program contains a *reference* to the implementing assembly.

See also [What's the difference between Type and TypeInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699863/whats-the-difference-or-relationship-between-type-and-typeinfo)

Comment: Is the'reference'here the same concept as it in "reference and pointer"? @John Wu

Comment: Sort of, but instead of pointing at a memory address, a type reference points to an assembly (including version and strong name if applicable) and type name.

Answer (score 0):

A type definition happens when you define a new type through a class, a struct, an interface or an enum.

A type reference is a collection of information about a type, e.g. its name or its members.

The `System.Type` class is able to represent a type, but not define a type.
When you call `typeof(TypeName)` or `object.GetType()`, you will deal with representations of types with objects of `System.Type`.

You can not directly instantiate an object of a type by just using a `System.Type` object. It only describes the type, but not *is* the type. That's why it is called a reference.

Answer (score 0):

A *type definition* implies the actual implementation of the type, such as, for example if it is a class, it means the definition of the class (with all its properties and fields).

A *type reference*, simply means that `System.Type` contains the details of a particular type, that is, it is the meta-data about the Type.