# Why is Assembly.GetTypes() triggering a AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event?

Tags: c#, reflection

using C# .Net Framework with Visual Studio 2019 & Unity container, as part of registering types in my module initializer (a class called from an assembly attribute which specifies my module initializer class), I want to scan through all the types in the assembly with Assembly.GetTypes() and look for a custom attribute, and register the types with a property from that custom attribute.

However, Assembly.GetTypes() is triggering a AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve which causes issues because of dependencies.  How come it is doing this?  Is there a way to go through types of an assembly without it trying to resolve references?

Comment: I would say it is trying to resolve some basetype/interface it encounters, or some property/field type. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30700065/613130 , especially the comment where it is explained that Microsoft wanted to make `Type` to be "light" but in the end they reversed the idea

Comment: yes it is... but why?

Comment: Probably to build a `Type` object (really a `RuntimeType`, that is the type that implements the abstract type `Type`) the .NET needs some information about its base type, or its interfaces, or the types of its properties/methods/..., and so it has to chain-load the related assemblies. It was for this reason that Microsoft wanted to introduce the "lighter" `TypeInfo`